# Laravel 5.2 eloquent relationship eager fetching

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I have extended my user model to have a role, the tables are as follows

```
users(id,name,email,password,remember_token, role_id,created_at,updated_at)
roles(id,name,description,created_at,updated_at)
```

then the User model is

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function role()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Role', 'id', 'role_id');
    }

}
```

and the Role model is

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model {

    protected $table = 'roles';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'role_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

I am returning the Users as json and i want them to eager fetch the role using query builder

```
$users = DB::table('users')->skip($skip)->take($size)->get();
```

the output i am getting is

```
{"id":1,"name":"Vinnie Ashken","email":"ashken@eml.cc","password":"$2y$10$fsSxekoktUV5xqe02hMZIuWVRpykmMvjGa.AJUriCEX.KPRfj.Yk.","role_id":1,"remember_token":"184J9pVLf9N2yQ5YfD9Yf5d88uavn0dCFGsAaXnamXKiIbLugIKAVJTmS1t6","created_at":"2016-03-16 00:23:56","updated_at":"2016-03-16 00:42:56"}
```

what i want is

```
{"id":1,"name":"Vinnie Ashken","email":"ashken@eml.cc","password":"$2y$10$fsSxekoktUV5xqe02hMZIuWVRpykmMvjGa.AJUriCEX.KPRfj.Yk.","role":{"id":1, "name":"Administrator","description":"test"},"remember_token":"184J9pVLf9N2yQ5YfD9Yf5d88uavn0dCFGsAaXnamXKiIbLugIKAVJTmS1t6","created_at":"2016-03-16 00:23:56","updated_at":"2016-03-16 00:42:56"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the full Eloquent model (`User::`) instead of the bare query builder (`DB::table('users')`).  Then you'll be able to use [`with`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) and other Relationship methods (in addition to all of the query builder methods):

```
$users = App\User::with('role')->skip($skip)->take($size)->get();
```

Comment: that gives me the exception 

    BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2161:
    Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::with()

Comment: Try using `User::` instead of `DB::table(...)`